# Use the Raspberry Pi as a Git server

Tags: archlinux, software-installation, server

How do I settup Git as a Git server like [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub), so I can create private repositories, etc.?

I have installed [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29). It's up and running smoothly and also Git with GITWEB works perfect. The only thing I don't get is how to use it as a server for my private repositories.

How can I do this? It there a good tutorial, because I haven't found anything really usable yet..

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

Comment: Git runs fine just with your own account from where you can SSH to the box.  Do you need more?

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic. Setting up a Git server is in no way specific to the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 4):

There's a book about called *[Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book)*, freely available and downloadable over the Internet. That book has the "[Git on the Server](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server)" chapter, that explains in thorough details how to install Git in different configurations according to your needs.

Comment: You should answer with an explanation, not with a reference

Comment: @GuySoft please, read the question thoroughly next time. OP asked for a tutorial, and I gave him one.

Comment: Ok, my bad. I guess at least you can link to that chapter.

Answer (score 2):

## Setting up a Git server (multi-user)

### Handle Git user

Install [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/master-toc.html) or [gitosis](https://github.com/res0nat0r/gitosis)

### Allow web access

Install [gitweb](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gitweb)

#### Notes

I prefer gitolite.

---

## Setting up a Git server (single-user)

### Git user

#### Create Git user

1. Create Git user

   - `sudo useradd -m git`
   - `sudo passwd git`
2. Add your key to your Git user (from another machine)

   - `ssh-copy-id -i /path/to/id.pub git@host`

#### Lock down Git user

`vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
Match User git
#ChrootDirectory /home/git/  #Look into this and see if you want it enabled.
AllowTCPForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
PasswordAuthentication no
```

`sudo service ssh restart`

#### Create your Git repository

`sudo su - git`

`mkdir /home/git/reponame.git`

`cd /home/git/reponame.git`

`git init --bare`

Look into using Git hooks to push code to another location when updating (post-update).

#### Push to your new repository

`git push git@host:reponame.git master`